How to select Articles that contain a specific string in the title or description or is tagged with a tag that contains the same string in Rails
I am working on a Rails application.

ruby: ruby-3.2.2
rails: 7.1.0
Postgresql: 16

As the title suggests, I am looking to retrieve from the database a series of articles through a search API.
To simplify, I have a route:
GET /search/articles?keywords=programming

I have those 3 models:
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagable_tags
  has_many :articles, through: :tagable_tags, source: :tagable, source_type: "Article"
end

class TagableTag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :tagable, polymorphic: true
end


class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagable_tags, as: :tagable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tagable_tags

  def self.find_by_keywords(keywords, page = 1, per = 50)
    sanitized_keywords = sanitize_sql_like(keywords.downcase)
    # Some solution here ...
  end
end

I've tried something like this, but it does an inner join I think so it would exclude some results
where('lower(articles.name) LIKE ?', "%#{sanitized_keywords}%")
      .includes(:tags)
      .references(:tags)
      .where('lower(tags.name) LIKE ?', "%#{sanitized_keywords}%")
      .page(page).per(per)

# This article should be returned
Article.create(
  {
    name: "Falling asleep while programming at work?",
    tags: []
  }
)

# This article should be returned
Article.create(
  {
    name: "An article name without the desired keyword",
    tags: [Tag.create(name: "programming")]
  }
)

# This article should NOT be returned
Article.create(name: "Another boring article", tags: [Tag.create(name: "nope")])


I want to be able to call this Article.find_by_keywords(params[:keywords]), and return the list of articles containing in the name or description the word programming OR if not present in those attributes, then return the articles tagged with a tag that has this keyword in it.
It would be great to be able to do so and being able to also use the kaminari pagination system in the query (the .page(x).per(y) you see in the class method).
Any recommendation?

Are there any errors or unexpected behaviour?  What is your test case?  Also, you've said you wanted to look for description, but I don't see a sql call to description for articles.

My solution was just not doing the expected result.
I've added some examples as you suggested, thanks :+1:

You actually have more of laundry list of requirements rather than a single coherent question - I'm going to try to break this down and answer at least one of the questions.
First off your assumed culprit is wrong. When you use includes together with references it just delegates to eager_load which does a single query with an OUTER JOIN:
-- Line breaks added for readibility --
irb(main):002:0> Article.references(:tags).includes(:tags).load
  SQL (6.2ms)  
  SELECT "articles"."id" AS t0_r0, "articles"."name" AS t0_r1, "articles"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "articles"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "tags"."id" AS t1_r0, "tags"."name" AS t1_r1, "tags"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "tags"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 
  FROM "articles" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "tagable_tags" ON "tagable_tags"."tagable_type" = $1 AND "tagable_tags"."tagable_id" = "articles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "tagable_tags"."tag_id"  [["tagable_type", "Article"]]
=> []

In fact it's a bit redundant to use includes as it's only merit is that it tries to be smart and only load the assocation when needed. If you know that you want to join just eager load it and cut out the indecision.
With that out of the way I'm assuming keywords is actually plural and not just named wrong and you want to match against a list of terms. One way to do that is:
Article.eager_load(:tags)
       .where(
         Tag.arel_table[:name].matches_any(['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%'])
       )

Which generates WHERE "tags"."name" ILIKE '%foo%' OR "tags"."name" ILIKE '%bar%' OR "tags"."name" ILIKE '%baz%'.
A bit more pretty and efficient would be:
WHERE "tags"."name" ILIKE ANY(ARRAY('%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%'))

To generate that query you can use something like this:
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tagable_tags, as: :tagable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tagable_tags

  # Gets articles with a least min_tag_count tag names matching a pattern
  def self.with_tags(*keywords, min_tag_count: 1)
    eager_load(:tags) # JOIN the tags table with an outer join
      .where(
        # "tags"."name" ILIKE ANY(ARRAY('%foo%', '%bar%'))
        Tag.arel_table[:name].matches(
          arel_any(
            arel_array(patternize_tag_names(keywords.flatten))
          )
        )
      )
  end

  private

  # be wary this is very naive and provides little real protection
  # against a SQL injection attack
  def self.patternize_tag_names(*values)
    values.flatten.map { |v| Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new("%#{sanitize_sql_like(v)}%") }
  end

  # -- The following can be refactored out of this class for resuse

  def self.arel_array(*values)
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'ARRAY',
      values
    )
  end

  def self.arel_any(*args)
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'ANY',
      args
    )
  end
end

irb(main):091:0> Article.with_tags('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
  SQL (0.6ms)  
SELECT "articles"."id" AS t0_r0, "articles"."name" AS t0_r1, "articles"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "articles"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "tags"."id" AS t1_r0, "tags"."name" AS t1_r1, "tags"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "tags"."updated_at" AS t1_r3 FROM "articles" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tagable_tags" ON "tagable_tags"."tagable_type" = $1 AND "tagable_tags"."tagable_id" = "articles"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "tagable_tags"."tag_id" 
WHERE "tags"."name" ILIKE ANY(ARRAY('%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%'))  [["tagable_type", "Article"]]
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
=>

If you want to combine that with a condition on the article description you would need to refactor this into something like a subquery instead but that's really the topic of a separate question, as is adding pagination or all the rest of the sprinkles on top.

Is this really a good solution? Hell no. It's a kludge thats short enough to fit into a stackoverfow answer. I would really look into libraries that exist for this problem unless you want to get deep into wheelmaking and full text searches.
